# Eliminar parte de una URL con Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Realizando una aplicación en Django (sin usar los form que trae el framework), al momento de acceder para editar un registro la URL que me muestra el navegador queda así:

[image: como queda la url en el navegador]

Hasta acá todo bien, pero una vez que edito el registro me queda la URL igual. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la URL me quede sin el Id que edité?

Archivo `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^empresa$', empresa, name='empresa'),
url(r'^empresaEditar/(?P<id_empresa>\d+)/$', empresaEditar, name='empresaEditar'),
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
def empresa(request):
    return render(request, 'estructuracion/empresa.html')

def empresaEditar(request, id_empresa):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        .
        .
        .
        msg='Registro modificado exitosamente'
        return HttpResponseRedirect('estructuracion/empresa',{'departamentos':departamentos, 'ciudades':ciudades,'msg':msg,})
    else:
        msg = validator.getMessage()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('estructuracion/empresa',{'departamentos':departamentos, 'business':business, 'ciudades':ciudades,'msg':msg,})

return render(request,'estructuracion/empresa.html',{'departamentos':departamentos, 'business':business, 'ciudades':ciudades,})
```

Otra pregunta es:

Como ven estoy retornando con `HttpResponseRedirect` pero a través de éste no me lleva al HTML los mensajes que le envié.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder enviar mensages por HttpResponseRedirect use los messages de django, estos mensajes se manejan con las etiquetas: debug, info, success,  warning y error. Toda la documentación esta aca https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/.

mi implementacion fue asi:

views.py

```
def usuario(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #aca va el codigo de mi views
        messages.success(request, 'Usuario creado exitosamente') #aca creo el mensaje con la etiqueta messages.success, podemos ver q mi mensaje va dentro de los parentesis despues de request dentro de comillas
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/estructuracion/usuario')
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'Se produjo un error') #Si no se cumple la condicion genero otro mensaje de alerta o error con la etiqueta messages.warning
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/estructuracion/usuario')
return render(request,'estructuracion/usuario.html')
```

Como podemos ver automaticamente se cargan los mensajes y solo tengo que mostrar los en el template:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if 'success' in message.tags %}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
            {{ message }}
        </div>
     {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 {% for message in messages %}
     {% if 'error' in message.tags %}
         <div class="alert alert-error">
             <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
             {{ message }}
         </div>
     {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 {% for message in messages %}
     {% if 'warning' in message.tags %}
         <div class="alert alert-danger">
             <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
             {{ message }}
         </div>
     {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Des esta forma segun la etiqueta(warning, error o success) se presentan el el template.(Estoy usando Bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, tu pregunta no la entiendo mucho en realidad, pero te puede ayudar a solucionarla, es usar las convenciones de Django para un mejor desarrollo.

Consiste en que cuando vas a hacer una redirección la hagas con una función que viene para ello, seria de la siguiente forma:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    return redirect('empresaEditar')
```

Es una forma mas limpia, con el nombre de la url, en caso de tener un namespace la url podría ser `return redirect('namespace:empresaEditar')`

Resulta que para pasar los datos, así como lo estas haciendo no es tan fácil, por lo que te propondré 2 opciones diferentes, las cuales son:

1.Enviar los datos por sesión:

```
...
# Lo envias en una vista
request.session['departamentos'] = departamentos
request.session['ciudades'] = ciudades
return redirect('empresaEditar')
...

# luego lo recuperas en tu otra vista de esta forma
def otra_vista(request):
    departamento = request.session.get('departamento', None)
    ciudades = request.session.get('ciudades', None)
    # haces lo que quieras con los datos
```

**NOTA:** Lo que envíes en la sesión es preferible que no sean objetos propios, es decir trata de enviar objetos propios de python como lo son: `str, int, dict, float, list, tuple, set, etc`, de lo contrario si tienes objetos como querysets, lo ideal seria serializarlos primero ya sea a JSON, YAML o XML, es tu desición.

2.Enviar los datos en la url (si envías querysets no es útil)

Para esto debes modificar tus urls y ahora aceptar parametros con las expresiones regulares, luego las rescatas de manera normal lo harias para una edición común:

```
...
# urls.py
url(r'^empresaEditar/(?P<id_empresa>\d+)/(?P<id_departamento>\d+)$', empresaEditar, name='empresaEditar'),

# luego, redireccionas usando reverse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
return redirect(reverse('empresaEditar', args=(empresa.id, departamento.id)))
# o
# return redirect(reverse('empresaEditar', kwargs={'id_empresa': empresa.id, 'id_departamento': departamento.id}))

# en tu otra vista (donde haces la redirección)
def otra_vista(request, id_empresa, id_departamento):
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    empresa = get_object_or_404(Empresa, id=id_empresa)
    departamento = get_object_or_404(Departamento, id=id_departamento)
```

Espero haberte ayudado
    ...